# Different domain names redirects to different languages

Tags: apache

I recently bought few others domain names for my project.

My question is very simple..

I want to coordinate each domain name on different language in my project..

```
Language                Lauguage folder        Different domains

English                 www.mysite.com/en      www.mysite.com

Spanish (Spain)         www.mysite.com/es      www.mysite.es

German (Germany)        www.mysite.com/de      www.mysite.de
```

On this above example..

if somebody goes to www.mysite.de, system redirects them to www.mysite.com/de/ and hide the /de/ from the url.

if somebody goes to www.mysite.es, system redirects them to www.mysite.com/es/ and hide the /es/ from the url.

if somebody goes to www.mysite.en, system redirects them to www.mysite.com/com/ and hide the /en/ from the url.

any idea how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the language directories are phsyical directories in your site, you don't need to use rewrite. It's as simple as declaring a virtual host for each language in your apache conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite/en
    ServerName www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite/de
    ServerName www.mysite.de
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite/es
    ServerName www.mysite.es
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:

I think I understand the situation now.

How about some redirect rules?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/en/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/de/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/es/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?$ /en/$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/de/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?$ /de/$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/es/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?$ /es/$1  [L,QSA]
```

EDIT 2:

edited the rewrite conds to still allow the old format www.mysite.com/de etc.

Comment: I want to do this stuffs on the server.. via htaccess file or mod_alias file.

Comment: Are your sites languages in different physical directories? Also, do you have access to change the conf files? If the answer is yes to both, then my answer is the optimal solution. If the answer is no to any one, then you can only use rewrite. mod_alias is not available in htaccess.

Comment: yes.. my website is in 5 different languages.. and each language works if i go via www.example.com/es so it loads spanish contents and it works the same with others. So i recently bought few domain for specific market for better SEO system.. So i want that my website´s domain in spanish would be www.example.es and so on and on... Any idea how to do this.. I m totally fed up for finding the solution... Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I understand the situation now. can you try my new answer in your htaccess?

Comment: i tried this way.. but whenever i pass www.example.es/test,it redirects to... http://www.example.es/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/en/index.php/pt/test

Comment: this doesn't make much sense, please use my updated rules, clear your browser cache and try again